# Значение потерь NaN при обучении нейронной сети

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Пробою сделать прототип нейронки, менял различные параметры (lr, число нейронов и т.д.), но на выходе loss все равно NaN.

```
X = data.values[:, :-1]
Y = data.values[:, -1]
Y = Y.reshape(-1, 1)
# размеры X = (100000, 16), Y = (100000, 1)

xScaler, yScaler = MinMaxScaler(), MinMaxScaler()
xScaler.fit(X)
yScaler.fit(Y)
xScaled = xScaler.transform(X)
yScaled = yScaler.transform(Y)
xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(xScaled, yScaled, test_size=0.2)

# Нейронная сеть
model = Sequential()
model.add(BatchNormalization(input_shape=(xTrain.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=1e-2), loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])

history = model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, epochs=10, batch_size=128,
                    validation_split=0.2, verbose=1)

plt.plot(history.history['mae'],
            label='Средняя абсолютная ошибка на обучающем наборе')
plt.plot(history.history['val_mae'],
            label='Средняя абсолютная ошибка на проверочном наборе')
plt.xlabel('Эпоха обучения')
plt.ylabel('Средняя абсолютная ошибка')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Результат: `Epoch 1/10 500/500 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: nan - mae: nan - val_loss: nan - val_mae: nan` все 10 эпох

Comment: Очевидно у вас есть NaNs во входных данных. От них необходимо избавиться перед тем как подавать данные на вход сети

Comment: Спасибо! Так и есть - в 85 строках были NaNs

Comment: Это и понятно - результатом любой арифметической операции в которой участвует хотя бы один NaN будет NaN ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема видимо в ваших данных, хотелось бы их посмотреть. Я попробовал ваш код на случайных данных:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100000, 16))
# далее ваш код
```

И всё работает, сетка учится, хотя и плохо (что понятно - данные то случайные).

[image: nn-score]

Вы можете попробовать для начала взять случайные данные как у меня и проверить на них. Если сетка будет учиться, значит надо смотреть, что у вас за данные, наверняка в них какие-то проблемы. А если будут и на них `NaN`, то, вероятно, проблема в версиях библиотек, нужно смотреть опять же конкретику - какие версии `Python` и `Keras` у вас стоят. Я проверял ваш код на `Google Colab`.

Проблема была в наличии в данных `NaN`, как верно предположил MaxU.